# Fixing detached head with a tag

Tags: git, garbage-collection, git-branch, git-tag, git-detached-head

Is it possible to fix a detached head with a tag? In other words, is it possible to prevent garbage collector deleting commits in a detached head with a tag at the last commit?

Every other post that I've found talk about creating a branch in the detached head to prevent losing commits that have been created in this state before leaving to another branch.

As I understand, the major difference between a tag and a branch is the branch moving with the head compared to the tag which stays at the exact same position where it was created.

In my scenario, I've checked out with an SHA-1 and then done a couple of commits from this point. Before leaving, I want to put a bookmark and I think in term of semantic, a tag would be better than a branch to go back later.

I don't have any problem creating a branch at this point instead of a tag if this is the only thing that I can do but I'm wondering about the behavior of git internally with tags and branches with relation with a detached head.

Also, conceptually, if someone does not agree with me about creating a tag instead of a branch, in this case, an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You have two good answers so far; I'll add a comment: it depends on what you mean by *fix*. A detached HEAD is not *broken* in the first place, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a tag will prevent garbage collection the same way a branch does. Only unreachable commits are eligible for garbage collection, and git checks every ref to check if the commit is reachable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not incorrect to put a tag to save some commit for future. There are, however, some downsides:

- `git fetch` or `push` with some options copy all tags to target side, without any mapping. So any private temporary tag may end up in common namespace.
- having too many tags may cause issues in GUIs

overall I would say that tags are more intended as public permanent milestones, for example releases.

There are more options to consider:

- for some time, commit is not collected and accessible through reflog
- it can be a branch, it is not a problem if it's not changing
- it can be a reference in yet another namespace than `tags` or `branches`. this is for example what bisect does for intermediate marks
- it can be merged to dedicated collect-all branch. This is what I use in local development

Comment: Your answer is very clear and good but the main part of my question is more oriented about preventing commits to be garbage collected. However, I will follow your advice considering tags only for public permanent milestones. In this case, my rule of thumb is to only add tag to an existing branch and in the majority of cases, only to permanent branches to prevent deleting branches that would delete tag. I use git-flow and then, tags will be in 99% of the cases in the master branch.